# One To Many Java Spring list return empty

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

everybody.
when i called /users to getAll users, my ideas list return empty. How can i get user ideias when i called findAll users?
Do i need to implements something in UserRepository?
Its seems weird to me, because every time i called /users resource, the ideas list return empty.
Is that right?
It will always return empty in a one to many relationship?
If i want to implement this, do i need to implements some JPQL in UserRepository?

Class user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_user")
public class User implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Idea> ideas = new ArrayList<>();

public User() {

}

public User(Long id, String name) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public List<Idea> getIdeas() {
    return ideas;
}





@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    User other = (User) obj;
    return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
}

}
```

Class idea:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_idea")
public class Idea implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String title;
private String description;

@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
private Instant date;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;

public Idea() {
    
}

public Idea(Long id, String title, String description, Instant date, User user) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.date = date;
    this.user = user;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}



public Instant getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Instant date) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(id);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Idea other = (Idea) obj;
    return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
}



}
```

User repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

}
```

User service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

@Autowired
private UserRepository repository;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<UserDTO> findAll() {

    List<User> list = repository.findAll();

    return list.stream().map(x -> new UserDTO(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());

}

}
```

User Resource

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserResource {

@Autowired
private UserService service;

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> findAll() {
    
    List<UserDTO> list = service.findAll();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(list);
}

}
```

Table Idea:

[image]

Table users:

[image]

Insomnia:

[image]

Comment: Does the record exist in database?

Comment: yess. Iam working now. I`ll update with a database screenshot.

Comment: This is a commonly asked question with many answers. You have a bidirectional relationship and might be forgetting JPA caches entities - It is up to you to set both sides of a bidirectional relationship as these are just java objects. So every time you  set Idea.user reference, you should also add that idea to the user's ideas list and save it to keep the object model in synch with the database. Alternatively, you can force a reload using entityManager.fresh(user) - if there is data, it will get read back in. If this doesn't help, show the SQL involved, especially on the refresh.

Comment: i updated with screenshots. Probably i have to do some consult and update my user list. But not make sense to me this empty list...